# How to pass values from Fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Android Development. I am trying to pass values from fragment to activity, but after so many tries I am unable to get the answer...

This is my Fragment :

```java
public OtpGentation(int OTP)
{
    this.OTP =OTP;
}
public OtpGentation(String number1, String email1, String password)
{
    number = number1;
    mail = email1;
    pass = password;
}

public OtpGentation() {


}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.otp, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    new OTPAsyncManager().execute();

    etxotp =(EditText)rootview.findViewById(R.id.etxotp);
    btnNext = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.nextToOTP);
    btnCancel =(Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.cancel);

    //etxotp.setText(OTP);
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            if (etxotp.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Enter OTP ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {
                int enteredOtp = Integer.parseInt(etxotp.getText().toString());
                if (enteredOtp ==OTP)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "OTP Matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
                    bun.putString("no",number);
                    bun.putString("ma",mail);
                    bun.putString("pa",pass);
                    Intent subintent = new Intent(getContext(),SubmitRegistration.class);
                    subintent.putExtras(bun);
                    startActivity(subintent);



                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Enter Correct OTP ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }


        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {

            fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            HomeScreen fragmentOne = new HomeScreen();

            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentOne)
                    .addToBackStack("")
                    .commit();

        }
    });


    return rootview;
}
```

And this is the class where I want to pass values

Comment: It looks like your question is incomplete

Comment: is that code gives you an error if it is yes show us it

Answer (score 2):

You should create an interface in your fragment and you should implement the interface to your Activity class.

For example, in your Fragment :

```
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

you can send any value like this:

```
        // Send the event to the host activity
        mCallback.onArticleSelected(position);
```

And your activity should be like this :

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    ...

    public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
        // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
        // Do something here to display that article
    }
}
```

For more information you can check [the offical documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Implement) :

Comment: onAttach(Activity activity)  : deprecated now.

Comment: yes, onAttach (Context context) makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i use , This works but its not a good practice

Inside your activity write getters and setters for the data which you want to pass , for example  if you want to pass a string name write

```
  String   fileName;

 public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}
public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

in your fragment

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    Context contextCheckClass;
    private String fileName;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View group=(View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_highlight, null);

         fileName=((MainActivity) getActivity()).setFileName("Your String to pass to activity");    //set what ever string you want to pass

    return group;
}

 }
```

if you do this way you cant use this fragment at any other location that MainActivity

if you want to access the same fragment from different activities then

in your fragment create a constructor passing context  .You would notice that it will give a warning about avoiding non default constructors just ignore it or disable check

```
   public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private String fileName;
    Context contextCheckClass;

    public YourFragment (Context ctx) {
        this.contextCheckClass=ctx;
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View group=(View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_highlight, null);
    if(contextCheckClass instanceof MainActivity){ //write your Activity name here
        //This fragment is called from MainActivity
         fileName=((MainActivity) getActivity()).getFileName(); 

        }
        else {
        //This fragment is called from some other activity
         }

    return group;
}
```

To Load this Fragment pass activity context to it

```
 YourFragment yourFragment =new YourFragment (MainActivity.this);
 getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.LL_Fragment, yourFragment)
.addToBackStack(null)
.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might come here sometime, please be informed that the answers in this thread have become outdated. The Fragment library now provides two options for communication: a shared ViewModel and the Fragment Result API. Please refer to the official docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate).