# Android Studio 3.0 lint warnings for references to activity

Tags: android, lint, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading my project to use Android Studio 3.0 with API level 27.0.0 (Android 8.1) I get a lot of new lint warnings related to using getActivity() inside a fragment (which I thought was perfectly all right).

Examples:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.pavingreport_dialog_menu, menu);
```

Both examples complains about null exceptions.

Example:

```
Method invocation 'getMenuInflater' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

I know I can fix this by adding activity as a field and initialize it during onCreate or something, but this only removes the warning...

Questions:

1. Is referring to the Activity using getActivity not the way to go? What is best practice?
2. Is this a 'bug' in AS that I can ignore?

Comment: What is the specific Lint warning? That `getActivity()` might return a `null` value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass values from Fragment to Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427759/how-to-pass-values-from-fragment-to-activity)

Comment: use the suggested approach , so instead sending data , let that overridden function inflate the menu

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh I think you have misunderstood my question. I am asking why getActivity() suddenly starts to give me lint warnings.

Comment: [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786011/how-to-fix-getactionbar-method-may-produce-java-lang-nullpointerexception)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getActivity()` in `Fragment` got the `@Nullable` annotation with support libraries 27.0.0. Thanks to Jake. Meaning this is now working as expected since it can return null.

Comment: Yes. I know that he did, and also thought that might have been the reason. But where in the documentation does it say that the activity can be null?

Comment: If the fragment is not attached to the activity or detached you'll get null from the call.

Comment: This answer seems to address part (2) of the OP's question (the why), but not (1) (what we're supposed to practically do about it).

Comment: It's his decision. Either work without the Activity or throw an exception.